Subsetting data in a dataframe when we dont know the exact subset number
Here I have some data and I'm trying to access the part of the dataframe (json format) with the highest number as that will always contain what I need, in this example that is [[4]] but in other occasions it could be anything in 1,2,3 or 4. Is there any way we can swap the 4 here for something that fits all? The only other thing I have which we could use to work this out is another part of the data (top example seen below) where we know we have 4 subsets with "All" always being the max number that we are after (bottom example seen below). I was thinking maybe we can use $names here to work this out then insert that result into $places[[4]] to get where I need to be.
dat$data$key$name[[1]]$names
"1"   "2"   "3"   "All"

dat$data$key$name[[1]]$places

[[1]]
example of how my data looks

[[2]]
example of how my data looks

[[3]]
example of how my data looks

[[4]]
here is the data I want to get


You could use tail() to get the last element

You can use length.
> dat$data$key$name$name1$places[[length(dat$data$key$name$name1$places)]]
[1] "qux"
> dat$data$key$name$name2$places[[length(dat$data$key$name$name2$places)]]
[1] "quux"

To avoid repetition we can use brackets in Map.
> Map(`[[`, 
+     lapply(dat$data$key$name, `[[`, 'places'),
+     lengths(lapply(dat$data$key$name, `[[`, 'names')))
$name1
[1] "qux"

$name2
[1] "quux"


Data:
> dput(dat)
list(data = list(key = list(name = list(name1 = list(names = list(
    "1", "2", "3", "All"), places = list("foo", "bar", "baz", 
    "qux")), name2 = list(names = list("1", "2", "3", "4", "All"), 
    places = list("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux"))))))


If your original data is actually JSON
json = 
    '{"data": {
        "key": {
            "name": {
                "names": ["1", "2", "3", "All"],
                "places": ["A", "B", "C", "ME"]
            }
        }
    }}'


You could access the element directly using JMESpath and CRAN rjsoncons package
> library(rjsoncons)
> j_query(json, '$.data.key.name.places[(@.length-1)]', as = "R")
[1] "ME"

If the data is more like as @jay.sf presents
json = '{
    "data": {
        "key": {
            "name": {
                "name1": {
                    "names": ["1", "2", "3", "All"],
                    "places": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
                },
                "name2": {
                    "names": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "All"],
                    "places": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

or
json = '{
    "data": {
        "key": {
            "name": [
                {
                    "names": ["1", "2", "3", "All"],
                    "places": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
                },
                {
                    "names": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "All"],
                    "places": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'

then the query adds [*] to name, as
> j_query(json, '$.data.key.name[*].places[(@.length - 1)]', as = "R")
[1] "qux"  "quux"

